# Floating input pin error on my rover schematic of altium designer

Tags: altium, error, schematic, floating-pin

I am receiving "contains floating input pins" errors on my altium designer schematic (among other issues) despite the wires being correctly connected, and each port and respective component being identified as either an input, output, or bidirectional. I think the issue pertains to the way I am handling sheet symbols. I am following this video quite explicitly, but am still getting red squiggles under the stepper motor sheet:

https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=3G5RJwxPA3g&ab_channel=CC2511JCU

I am fairly new to Altium and have only designed a pcb for a cnc machine before, but am trying to make a custom pcb for a reasonably simple rover. The motor drivers I am using at TI drv8825, and will be controlling nema 17s. I intend to program it all through a raspberry pi 3 b+. If anyone has any solutions that would be greatly appreciated. Thanks!

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

[image]

Answer (score 1):

This error usually arises when your Input port is not connected to the IC Pin. There are some reasons due to which you are getting error.

1. Maybe you didn't properly connect a wire to the IC or any component
2. Maybe your wire isn't connected to the Port you defined.
3. The main reason that I can see is that maybe your grid is not properly setup. When your grid is not properly setup then you often get this "Floating pin error" it may seem that they are connected but they are not. Kindly adjust the grid and then try again.